# Would the compiler optimize this or do I need the assignment?

Tags: c++, optimization

If I have a method call in a for loop that is the same for all iterations of the loop - is the compiler smart enough to optimize it?

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++ ) {
        *destinationPointer++ = identityArray[j] * (1 / powf(2, valueFromAboveInMethod));
 }
```

Or should I be explicit and assign it to a value before the loop?

```
 float value = 1 / powf(2, valueFromAboveInMethod);

 // populate the array
 for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++ ) {
        *destinationPointer++ = identityArray[j] * value;
 }
```

I'd be happier if the compiler did something awesome here and I didn't have to use the 4 bytes for the float - this is inside a recursive method.

Comment: "and I didn't have to use the 4 bytes for the float" - Is that really a bad thing?

Comment: Let's say the compiler did do this optimization; where would it store the value between iterations if not in a `float`?

Comment: Not mention that the optimized version is more readable...

Comment: I'm going to guess the compiler doesn't have enough information to optimize away the `powf` call--it could be returning a random value for all the compiler knows.

Comment: Try defining the "value" as "const float value".  Since it doesn't change within the loop, telling the compiler that it is constant may help the compiler optimize the code better.

Answer (score 2):

I personally would use a variable here. Not only because it may provide better code, but also because it shows to anyone reading the code that the value doesn't change [I'd give it a better variable-name than "value", however]. I do expect the compiler to actually pre-calculate the value, but as has been mentioned, it does rely on the compiler understanding that `powf` is a pure function (has no side-effects and give the same result for the same input every time).

Any additional storage as a consequence of using an extra variable in a recursive call would either be a case of "well, it shouldn't matter" or "you are playing very close to the edge of the abyss of stack overflow". Stack overflow is probably one of the worst types of crashes, as it gives absolutely no warning or way to recover, since the program needs to use a stack to recover, and it may well be the only stack available that overflowed... If your recursive function is either unbounded or you can't guarantee that that the number of recursive calls are well within the limits of the stack, then I would suggest you should redesign this function. Deep recursion is often quite inefficient as well as the fact that it's prone to crashing with stackoverflow [and with a stack that contains forty-thousand calls to the same function, which makes it very easy to figure out why it crashed, but not necessarily easy to figure out the original cause of the deep recursion].

--
Mats

Answer (score 1):

It depends on with what options do you compile it. Usually even with minimal optimization enabled compilers deal with such simple optimizations, however it's better to just do it yourself as you have written in the second code. Anyway if compiler will optimize it, it will keep `additional 4 bytes` too, because value need to be stored anywhere.

Comment: Not certainly, it could store the value in a register which is freely available without saving. Depends on how many registers are available.

Comment: He noted that it is located inside recursive method, so there will be a need to store 4 byte for each instance in the stack at the moment.

Comment: Not necessarily. If it's a local calculation it can be held in a register that is not saved. There is no [from what I can tell] call to the function itself in the section of code posted.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler may not be smart enough to realize powf is stateless.

When in doubt, compile to assembler and check it yourself.